# Heroku direct syslog logging

Tags: logging, heroku, syslog

The current solution that Heroku uses is, that all the standard output is forwarded into syslog and then through the router into one.

Would it be possible to send log messages directly to herokus' syslog. I am using Node and the default way to log is to use the `console.log` which is not very performance wise function in larger scale. Or if this is not possible, is there any alternative ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope -- Heroku's log is just an aggregate stream of Dyno log environments. `console.log` should scale just fine though -- even if you're doing millions of log requests, you should be OK.

Comment: After some research it seems true, so Ill close the topic.